# Raspberry Pi Wifi Access Point Ubuntu Mate

Tags: pi-3, networking, wifi

How can I set up a wifi access point on a Rasberry Pi 3 Model B running Ubuntu Mate? Many other people mention using Raspbian, but none of those methods have worked so far. Thus, I was wondering how I can setup an AP in terminal on the Raspberry Pi that I have.

Comment: You wrote: "*Many other people mention using Raspbian, but none of those methods have worked so far.*" I know at least three setups with Raspbian which I have tested to work, confirmed by many users.

Comment: Hi, I meant using methods for Raspbian being applied to Ubuntu Mate. However, I was able to figure it out.

Comment: If you have a solution so please make an answer and explain it in short. This will finish the question and show others that it has a solution and they do not try to help you for nothing.